# Read data from text file with scanner and multiple delimiters in JAVA

Tags: java, regex, parsing, java.util.scanner

I have a text file containg the following data:

```
20;
1: 39, 63;
2: 33, 7;
16: 33, 7;
3: 45, 27;
4: 8, 67;
5: 19, 47;
6: 15, 40;
...
20: 65, 54;
```

first integer is the amount of entries in the list.

Each line is an entry. So entry 1 has x y coordinates 39 and 63 respectively.
I understand that I can use different delimiters to read the data, but i'm not quite sure how to achieve that. Currently I'm using `split()`.

The following code reads each line, but this obviously doesn't work since the delimiters are not set propperly. Is there a good way to get this to work?

```
String[] temp = sc.next().split(";");
int productAmount = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
sc.nextLine();

for (int i = 0; i < productAmount; i++) {
    int productID = sc.nextInt();
    int x = sc.nextInt();
    int y = sc.nextInt();
    Product product = new Product(x, y, productID);
    productList.add(product);
}
```

Comment: [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) has a `String` as its parameter. So you can use multiple delimiters following `regex` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the tokens can be converted to integers after removing the last character from them. You can make use of this property of the given data. Define a method like this:

```
int integerFromToken(String str) {
    return Integer.valueOf(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1));
}
```

which returns the integer part of a token (`39,` returns `39`, `63;` returns `63` etc.). Now use the method to get integer values from tokens (obtained with `sc.next()`):

```
int productID = integerFromToken(sc.next());
int x = integerFromToken(sc.next());
int y = integerFromToken(sc.next());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
String[] temp = sc.next().split("[ ,:;]");
```

then your `temp` variable will hold only the numbers. The string `"[ ,:;]"` is a [regular expression](http://www.slideshare.net/rajkissu/regular-expressions-101), and it means any character in the square brackets will be a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to what **Croo** said, but I get a compilation error when I use his method.

In order to avoid matching empty strings by including spaces as delimiters, it makes more sense to me to allow them and use a call to `trim` to get rid of them.

Also it be useful to know that the `Scanner` can be given a `regex` expression as a delimiter and then calls to `next` can be used to navigate the input.

```
sc.useDelimiter("[,:;]");
int productAmount = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
int x, y, productID, i;
for (i = 0; i < productAmount; i++) {
    productID = Integer.parseInt(sc.next().trim());
    x = Integer.parseInt(sc.next().trim());
    y = Integer.parseInt(sc.next().trim());
    productList.add(new Product(x,y,productID));
}
```